# Views caching not working for Taxonomy listing pages

Tags: views, caching

I was able to turn on Views caching (both time-based for a few, and content-based for others) successfully.  However, for my "taxonomy/term/%" pages (and their respective "/feed? pages as well) if I turn on any kind of caching, I get an empty page. Not the WSOD, but just the title and no listings.  Further, the pager is all screwy - the page numbers point to pages for OTHER taxonomy terms.  I can't seem to find a pattern.

I did find this discussion on d.o but it's not much help: http://drupal.org/node/1430650

What's killing me is that these pages are seriously about 98% of my site's traffic - literally tens of thousands of page views per day.  If I can get these cached it would give me a huge performance increase.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried doing a print_r(), dpm(), etc. on the [cache_get()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!cache.inc/function/cache_get/7) and [cache_set()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!cache.inc/function/cache_set/7) functions to see what's going on? The output of this tends to be somewhat verbose, so I generally like to do an error_log(), then go to the PHP error log and see all the calls to cache_get and cache_set to see if I detect a pattern. This would give you a concrete idea of what and what is not getting cached.